# Angular 2 Dynamically bootstrap app components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible for Dynamically bootstrap app components depending on if the element exists.

Would want something like...

```
export class AppModule { 

constructor() {

}   

ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    for(let component of components) {
       if(document.querySelector(component.selector)){
           appRef.bootstrap(component);
       }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to check yourself if the element is available in the DOM and then call `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` or `appRef.bootstrap(component);` or otherwise skip calling it.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11730#issuecomment-252677321

Comment: So can not somehow look through the imported components and check against there selector in a loop. The reason why I ask this question is there could potentially be over 50 components,m which of course would make my app module file look a mess and also make it more difficult to maintain going forward.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You are potentially bootstrapping over 50 components?

Comment: @Johnwilliams You can just use the same array as you will declare in your `@NgModule` `entryComponents: [components]`

Comment: How do i access from with my class?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you want to access from what class?

Comment: @NgModule entryComponents ?

Comment: You can just pack the components in an array and pass this array to `entryComponents` and access the same array from the class. Is that what you want?

Comment: Can you not give an example in an answer ?

Comment: That's quite some work and your question is quite vague. Honestly I don't know what the problem is exactly you are trying to solve. I would need to torture my brain to find a plausible scenario that I could make an example of ;-) It would be easier if you'd elaborate more on your approach and where you're stuck and then to point out what can't work or what is missing to make it work.